# Removing moire patterns produced by GLSL shaders

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl

I have setup this minimal test case, which you can easily see the moire patterns produced by undersampling the oscilating red colour using a custom fragment shader ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yfr0ov2n/5/)).

What is the general technique for removing such patterns using GLSL? I assume it involves the derivatives extension, but I've never quite understood how to implement it. I basically have to do anti-aliasing, I think?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, antialias: true});
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientWidth, 1, 1000);

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 50, 50);
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent
});
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(sphere);

camera.position.z = 100;

var period = 30;
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  
  if (canvas.width !== canvas.clientWidth || canvas.height !== canvas.clientHeight) {
    renderer.setSize(canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight, false);
    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth /  canvas.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
  
  sphere.rotation.y -= clock.getDelta() * 2 * Math.PI / period;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
html, body, #canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r73/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
  }
</script>
<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  #define M_TAU 6.2831853071795864769252867665590

  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() {
    float w = sin(500.0 * M_TAU * vUv.x) / 2.0 + 0.5;
    vec3 color = vec3(w, 0.0, 0.0);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
  }
</script>
```

Update: I've tried to implement [super-sampling](https://jsfiddle.net/yfr0ov2n/13/), not sure if I have implemented it correctly but it doesn't seem to help too much.

Comment: @WacławJasper Using the uv coord was just an easy way to get this effect. The seam itself isn't creating the problem, otherwise you would only see the problem around the seam itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, the moire pattern here is a result of the high-contrast lines approaching the [Nyquist Frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency).  In other words, there's no good way to have a 1- or 2-pixel-wide high-contrast line smoothly shift to the next pixel over, without either introducing such artifacts, or blurring the lines to be indistinguishable.

You mentioned the derivatives extension, and indeed that extension can be used to figure out how quickly your UVs are changing in screen space, and thus, figure out how much blurring is needed to sort of sweep this problem under the rug.  In the modified version of your own example below, I attempt to use `fwidth` to turn the sphere red where the noise gets bad.  Try playing with some of the floats that are defined to constants here, see what you can find.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: canvas, antialias: true});
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientWidth, 1, 1000);

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 50, 50);
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
  fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent
});
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(sphere);

camera.position.z = 100;

var period = 30;
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  
  if (canvas.width !== canvas.clientWidth || canvas.height !== canvas.clientHeight) {
    renderer.setSize(canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight, false);
    camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth /  canvas.clientHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
  
  sphere.rotation.y -= clock.getDelta() * 2 * Math.PI / period;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
html, body, #canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r73/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() {
    vUv = uv;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
  }
</script>
<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
  #extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable

  #define M_TAU 6.2831853071795864769252867665590

  varying vec2 vUv;

  void main() {
    float linecount = 200.0;
    float thickness = 0.0;
    float blendregion = 2.8;
    
    // Loosely based on https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/1.16/Source/Shaders/Materials/GridMaterial.glsl#L17-L34
    float scaledWidth = fract(linecount * vUv.s);
    scaledWidth = abs(scaledWidth - floor(scaledWidth + 0.5));
    vec2 dF = fwidth(vUv) * linecount;
    float value = 1.0 - smoothstep(dF.s * thickness, dF.s * (thickness + blendregion), scaledWidth);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(value, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The only thing I could ask for is maybe further information or documentation on various techniques for this type of thing? Do they all basically just blur the high frequency stuff?

Comment: As far as I know that's the only solution: Pixel-based displays simply can't show frequencies higher than the pixel density.  In the code above, `thickness` and `blendregion` are specified in screen-space pixels thanks to `fwidth`, meaning the lines begin to overlap as they become spaced less than ~3 pixels apart.  Less than that and you only have 1 pixel for the line and 1 pixel for the gap, and things get messy when the lines don't stick to the pixel grid.

Comment: BTW, the logic this code is based on is more fully described in the book "3D Engine Design for Virtual Globes" by Cozzi and Ring, Listing 4.13.